# No me reconoce el comando ng la terminal -bash: ng: command not found

Tags: angular-cli

No se que he hecho que no me reconoce el comando ng en la terminal del mac.

He vuelto a desinstalar e instalar angular cli pero no consigo nada. Mi ordenador el un mac y veo respuesta de algo del PATH desconfigurado, pero todas las opciones que encuentro las veo en windows y no se como llegar por el mi mac al PATH para poder revertirlo.

Tampoco se que tendría que poner.

Alguien me puede ayudar?

Gracias

Comment: Yo verificaría par de cosas.. primero el node, que funcione.. segundo la carpeta /usr/local/bin ahi estan los links simbolicos que apuntan a comandos de programas bajo npm.. como el angular...

Comment: Ahora tampoco me funciona no se Antea por lo menos me daba la versión pero ahora ya ni reconoce el comando 

Comment: para ver tu path en mac usa `echo $PATH` en una consola. Ten en cuenta que para que `MacOs` reconozca el comando debes tener instalado node e instalar la dependencia. Para verificar si tienes instalado node en un terminal usa `node --version`.

Answer (score 1):

Si tienes instalado brew

el problema lo resolvi con el comando brew install angular-cli

me instalo todo. sin problema.

Comment: Por favor verifica tu respuesta, de tal forma que puedas responder la duda de alguien mas. ademas la parte de `angular-cli` es un paquete de node. https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Tenía el mismo problema y la respuesta de Guillermo Hernandez me sirvió, corrí el comando brew install angular-cli, se demoró, pero luego ya reconoció el comando ng y pude continuar. Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Revisa tu archivo `.bash_profile` (si existe)

```
nano ~/.bash_profile
```

Revisa si existe un export PATH que contenga alguna ruta invalida. La separacion entre rutas en MacOS es de `:`, no `:` como en windows.

Tambien puedes revisar el archivo de rutas globales (`/etc/paths`) para revisar si existe alguna ruta invalida.

Comment: No existe el .bash_profile tengo que generarme uno?

Answer (score 0):

Hola veo que tienes todavía el problema. En si estas pidiendo ayuda sobre `angular-cli`. Lo que debes entender es que es un paquete de `Node` para tus proyectos de `Angular`.

En si para corregir el error debes verificar tener instalado `Node`

en consola/terminal escribe:

```
node --version
```

Si te retorna algo como `12.X.X` por ejemplo quiere decir que estas usando la version 12 de node.

Ahora bien si tienes node instalado solo debes instalar `angular-cli` con

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

> la opción -g quiere decir que se va a instalar de forma global y lo puedas usar desde el directorio que prefieras.

En caso de que no tengas instalado node. [Descargar Node](https://nodejs.org/es/download/). Y continuar con los pasos anteriores